Changing color of oh-my-posh segment based on SSH session
The way I handle this now is by having two Session segments and having one of them (one that contains only an indicator icon) only appear when I'm connected to a machine via SSH.
I tried the following code:
"background_templates": [
  "{{ if .SSHSession }}#CB3B00{{ else }}#26BDBB{{ end }}"
],

... but it seems .SSHSession only works in the Session template.
Does anyone I know this is something OMP supports? I imagine I could do this by using the Command segment but I'd like to avoid that as I'm not sure what the performance hit would be.

Check the cross-segment doc, you can send properties from one segment to another.
